# Speed up RegionPlot (replacement with ContourPlot?)

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, regions

I want to plot a region with the following notebook:

```
Do[{d1[i] = RandomReal[{0, 1}], c1[i] = RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}]}, {i, 0,
    1001}];
Do[a[i] = 
   Rationalize[Sqrt[d1[i]]*Cos[c1[i]] + I*Sqrt[d1[i]]*Sin[c1[i]], 
    0], {i, 0, 1001}];
Do[c2[i] = RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}], {i, 0, 1001}];
Do[b[i] = 
  Rationalize[
   Sqrt[(1 - d1[i])]*Cos[c2[i]] + I*Sqrt[(1 - d1[i])]*Sin[c2[i]], 
   0], {i, 0, 1001}]

so2[t_, T_, a_, b_, x_, 
  z_] = (E^(-t - 1/
     T) (-b^2 E^(1/T) (2 - 3 E^(t/2) + E^t)^2 x^2 Conjugate[a]^2 + 
      b (-b E^(1/T)
           x ((-8 + 8 E^t - 9 E^(t/2) t + E^(3 t/2) t) (-1 + z) + 
            E^(1/T) (-8 + 8 E^t - 9 E^(t/2) t) (1 + z)) + 
         a ((-1 + E^t) (-20 + 24 E^(t/2) + E^t (-4 + t) - 9 t) (-1 + 
               z)^2 + E^(
             2/T) (20 - 24 E^(t/2) + 4 E^t + 9 t) (1 + z)^2 + 
            2 E^(1/T) (-4 (5 + x^2 - 5 z^2) + 
               12 E^(t/2) (2 + x^2 - 2 z^2) + 9 t (-1 + z^2) + 
               6 E^(3 t/2) (-2 + x^2 + 2 z^2) - 
               E^(2 t) (-2 + x^2 + 2 z^2) + 
               E^t (6 + 5 t - 13 x^2 - (6 + 5 t) z^2)))) Conjugate[
        a] Conjugate[b] + 
      E^(1/T) Conjugate[
        b]^2 (-a^2 (2 - 3 E^(t/2) + E^t)^2 x^2 + 
         a b x (-(-8 + 8 E^t - 9 E^(t/2) t + E^(3 t/2) t) (-1 + z) - 
            E^(1/T) (-8 + 8 E^t - 9 E^(t/2) t) (1 + z)) + 
         b^2 (-4 E^(2/T) (-1 + E^(t/2))^2 (1 + z)^2 - 
            E^(1/T) (8 - 16 E^(t/2) - 24 E^(3 t/2) + 4 E^(2 t) + 
               E^t (28 + 9 t)) (-1 + z^2) + 
            E^t (-1 + z)^2 (-24 - 9 t + 
               32 Cosh[t/2] + (-8 + t) Cosh[t] + 16 Sinh[t/2] + 
               t Sinh[t])))))/(2 b (-(-20 + 24 E^(t/2) + 
          E^t (-4 + t) - 9 t) (-1 + z) + 
      E^(1/T) (20 - 24 E^(t/2) + 4 E^t + 9 t) (1 + z)) Conjugate[b])

RegionPlot[
 Or @@ Flatten[
    Table[Re[so2[0.1 + t, 0.4, a[i], b[i], x, z]] < 0, {i, 0, 1000, 
      1}, {t, 0, 7, 0.1}], 1] && x^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 
  1}, {z, -1, 1}, AxesStyle -> Directive[26], 
 LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 26), FrameLabel -> {x, z}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{-0.5, 0.5}, None}, {{-0.5, 0.5}, None}}]
```

The code works, but it is extremely slow. I would like to vary the second parameter of the function so2, so I have to do similar calculation many times.

Is it possible to speed up the calculation?

I have tried to rewrite the code to use the ContourPlot with so2 equals zero, but I have failed. The output is not simply a boundary of RegionPlot, but the
sum of ContourPlots for different i, which does the figure unreadable. What is more the ContourPlot does not seem to work with Table, the code

```
ContourPlot[
 Flatten[Table[
   Re[so2[0.1 + t, 0.4, a[i], b[i], x, z]] == 0, {i, 0, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 
    5, 1}], 1], {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, AxesStyle -> Directive[26], 
 LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 26), FrameLabel -> {x, z}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{-0.5, 0.5}, None}, {{-0.5, 0.5}, None}}]
```

gives empty output (and I would also like to include  x^2 + z^2 = 1 somehow)...

---

Edit:

I have managed to make ContourPlot with Table work, with

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Flatten[{Table[
     Re[so2[0.1 + t, 0.4, a[i], b[i], x, z]] == 0, {i, 0, 50, 1}, {t, 
      0, 5, 0.1}], x^2 + z^2 == 1}, 2], {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[26], LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 26), 
 FrameLabel -> {x, z}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{-0.5, 0.5}, None}, {{-0.5, 0.5}, None}}]
```

which gives the output

[image: Output from above code]

The code is extremly fast (Timing: 26.1526) in comparision to RegionPlot as given above (with max. i=50 it is still not completed after 10 minutes...).

The problem is: if I make the maximal number i larger, I get an error:

Identity called with 4096 arguments; 1 argument is expected.

What is more from the above picture I would like to extract an RegionPlot as mentioned earlier.